# Chrome Extension Manifest.json invalid

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Now why in the world is this invalid.

Manifest.json:

```
{
     "name": “mything",
     "version": "1",
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "content_scripts": [{
         "js": [“engine.js”],
         "matches": ["http://www.agar.io/*”]
      }]
}
```

Error:

```
Failed to load extension from: ~/Desktop/AgarExpress
Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 2, column: 15, Unexpected token.
```

Line that is invalid is

```
"name": “mything",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If to believe [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/) “ != " . They dont have the same encoding, i remember i stumbled upon it as an issue with greek keyboard if I am not mistaken. This one is valid, also according to the text coloring of Stack Overflow:

```
{
    "name": "mything ",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["engine.js"],
        "matches": ["http://www.agar.io/*"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Works! Thank you so much!